# Representing a queue as a procedure with local state

Tags: lisp, scheme, sicp

From [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-22.html):

> Exercise 3.22.  Instead of
>   representing a queue as a pair of
>   pointers, we can build a queue as a
>   procedure with local state. The local
>   state will consist of pointers to the
>   beginning and the end of an ordinary
>   list. Thus, the make-queue procedure
>   will have the form

```
(define (make-queue)
  (let ((front-ptr ...)
        (rear-ptr ...))
    <definitions of internal procedures>
    (define (dispatch m) ...)
    dispatch))
```

> Complete the definition of make-queue
>   and provide implementations of the
>   queue operations using this
>   representation.

I wrote the following solution:

```
(define (make-queue)
  (let ((front-ptr '())
        (rear-ptr '()))
    (define (set-front-ptr! ptr) (set! front-ptr ptr))
    (define (set-rear-ptr! ptr) (set! rear-ptr ptr))
    (define (empty?) (null? front-ptr))
    (define (front-queue) 
      (if (empty?)
          (error "FRONT called with an empty queue" front-ptr)
          (car front-ptr)))
    (define (insert! item)
      (let ((new-pair (cons item '())))
        (cond ((empty?)
               (set-front-ptr! new-pair)
               (set-rear-ptr! new-pair)
               dispatch)
              (else
               (set-cdr! rear-ptr new-pair)
               (set-rear-ptr! new-pair)
               dispatch))))
    (define (delete!)
      (cond ((empty?)
             (error "DELETE! called with an empty queue" first-ptr))
            (else
             (set-front-ptr! (cdr front-ptr))))
      dispatch)
    (define (print) front-ptr)
    (define (dispatch m)
      (cond ((eq? m 'insert!) insert!)
            ((eq? m 'front-ptr) front-ptr)
            ((eq? m 'rear-ptr) rear-ptr)
            ((eq? m 'empty?) empty?)
            ((eq? m 'delete!) delete!)
            ((eq? m 'print) print)
            (else (error "No such procedure: dispatch" m))))
    dispatch))

(define q1 (make-queue))
((((q1 'insert!) 'a) 'print))
((((q1 'insert!) 'b) 'print))
((((q1 'delete!)) 'print))
((((q1 'delete!)) 'print))
```

How can it be improved?

Comment: Looking through your questions, you have a lot of titles that unnecessarily contain tags. You should only use titles to briefly describe what your program/method does.

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide implementations of the queue operations using this representation. In SICP this usually refers to syntactic sugar to make working with a data structure less awkward, e.g.

```
(define (queue-insert! q item)
    ((q 'insert!) item) )
```

Also I would prefer different operation names, e.g.

append! instead of insert!
front instead of front-ptr
...